# What's the purpose of objects in Java?

Tags: java, object

Today I had an interview for test automation in one of the MNC.

They asked me "why do we need to create an object?"

I explained about OOPs concepts with example of individual bank account holders. But he is not convinced. He just need a definition.

What could be a suitable answer for that question?

Comment: What was the context of the question? Did he ask that after some other question where there was an object that was created?

Comment: We don't **need** to create an object.

Comment: That was the first question he asked me

Comment: basically to use the class methods and its constructor

Comment: In big picture everything is an Object in Java.

Comment: You only need to create an object if you need an instance of the object. The question is circular and meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require an object to represent state.

At the most simple definition, a class defines behaviour and an instance of a class (an object) represents state.

Of course there are other things like static contexts which can also maintain state, which you can mention also, but above is the clearest answer which I believe they were looking for.

It also always helps to give an example. You could talk about, for example, an `Employee` class. You would need an object to represent *John* and another to represent *Jane*.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is kind of generic and does not give much value to an interview. But some generic question should have a generic answer, and here is mine:

We need to create objects in java so we can get instances that have a state inside our application. This allows us to have persistent encapsulated elements that contain any required information, and methods that operate with it.

Just plain basic OOP theory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why we create a object apart from basic oops

1) To bring up persistent state data to transactional state to perform action (curd and other) and persist back to data storage.(EJB, POJO,etc )

2) Creating handler to serve service and send fluid data across wire like web-service.

3)Stuctural behavior in action.for example you designed a class for a workflow and to make in action state we create a object and serve the behavior example validation , authorization , etc class

All in all to make design time architecture to response based live system